# How to read bytes in chunks to avoid out of memory exception? Or something else

Tags: memory, byte, out

after searching and trying to find a solution for 2 days i finnaly decided to post here to ask for help...

I have a code to read and write bytes of a file (like an hex editor) working very good taken from here: http://www.novahq.net/forum/showthread.php?t=42592
Here goes the code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Shared Function HexStringToByteArray(ByRef strInput As String)
As Byte()
        Dim length As Integer
        Dim bOutput As Byte()
        Dim c(1) As Integer
        length = strInput.Length / 2
        ReDim bOutput(length - 1)
        For i As Integer = 0 To (length - 1)
            For j As Integer = 0 To 1
                c(j) = Asc(strInput.Chars(i * 2 + j))
                If ((c(j) >= Asc("0")) And (c(j) <= Asc("9"))) Then
                    c(j) = c(j) - Asc("0")
                ElseIf ((c(j) >= Asc("A")) And (c(j) <= Asc("F"))) Then
                    c(j) = c(j) - Asc("A") + &HA
                ElseIf ((c(j) >= Asc("a")) And (c(j) <= Asc("f"))) Then
                    c(j) = c(j) - Asc("a") + &HA
                End If
            Next j
            bOutput(i) = (c(0) * &H10 + c(1))
        Next i
        Return (bOutput)
    End Function

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As
System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim myFile As String = "..\..\Test.jpg"
        Dim myBytes As Byte() =
My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllBytes(myFile)
        Dim txtTemp As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
        For Each myByte As Byte In myBytes
            txtTemp.Append(myByte.ToString("X2"))
        Next
        RichTextBox1.Text = txtTemp.ToString()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As
System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim myFile As String = "..\..\Test2.jpg"
        Dim myBytes As Byte() = HexStringToByteArray(RichTextBox1.Text)
        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes(myFile, myBytes, False)
    End Sub
End Class
```

This is working very good, BUT only with small/medium size files. If i try to load a 512MB or a bigger file i will get "System.OutOfMemoryException" error.

I know that in order to make this work (read bigger files without error) i have to read files in small pieces (or chunks whatever you wanna name it), or maybe read it byte by byte i suppose...

The only problem is that i couldn't find a way to do it. I did find some codes but for some reason i wasn't able to make that codes work :(

I apreciate if someone could give me a push on this.

...However, i've thinking and maybe i don't need to read the whole file because i just need to add some bytes to the end of the file and then remove those again.

**I'll try to explain what i need:**

I only need to add this "`504B0506000000000000000000000000000000000000`" bytes at the end of a zip in onder do blind/hide contents of zip and then i need to read in again and remove those bytes.

**a) Append bytes to the end of file**

**b) Remove those bytes again**

This sounds really simple but from all codes and examples i have found i couldn't adapt them to my code.

Thank you